# mklink error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: windows

I am trying to create a symbolic link on my win7 64bit machine to redirect the iTunes backup data to another drive.  I am pretty sure the syntax is correct but cannot understand how to clear this error.  I have tried both commands below which have the same error.  I am running in Administrator Command Window.  Could there be some corporate group policy preventing me from running this command?

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"
```

or

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"
```

*Error*

Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: which one is the original directory?

Comment: the original directory is C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup

Comment: Does the folder you're linking to on the E drive exist?  Does a folder of the same name as the link exist on the C drive?  Is the E drive formatted in NTFS?

Comment: The syntax is correct, before running this command, perform the following steps. Move all the contents of current mobilesync backup folder to E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup. Once done, delete the empty backup subfolder from "C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync".

A Junction can only be created if a subfolder with the same name does not exist at the location.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

the syntax is incorrect. `mklink` has the following synatx:

```
mklink [options] <Link> <Target>
```

`Target` is the file/folder that exists, and `Link` is the created one that *links* to the target.

so the command should be:

```
mklink /D "E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"  "C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"
```

See the Microsoft Documentation for [mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) usage.

Comment: I have gone through the docs and being so brief you would think it would be no problem to run.  However no luck, even reversing the link/target like you suggest results in the same error message.

Comment: then you should check that E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup folder does not exists

Comment: That worked.  I noticed that deleting the full path resulted in error: "The system cannot find the path specified." So I restored the path and deleted only the last folder in the path (Backup) and then it worked.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This creates a simlink, which does not redirect iTunes to another drive. It does the exact opposite - it directs another drive to the iTunes backup folder.

Answer (score 25):

The simplest way is to delete the `Backup` folder in the original `Apple Computer` folder on the `C:\` drive, but leave the `MobileSync` folder be. This is because you're trying to fake the existence of the `Backup` folder (so it must not exist already), but you also need its parents to exist.

Then, if we run the command:

`mklink /J "%AppData%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\iTunes Backups"`

Windows will hence create a hard link shortcut `Backup` on the `C:\` drive.

Comment: This is the correct answer which does what OP meant to do

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the `"file already exist error"`, until I used the `"%AppData%'`:

```
mklink /J "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "E:\iTune Backups"

Junction created for C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup <<===>> E:\iTune Backups
```

Note: Make sure you use straight quotes, otherwise you get a syntax command error.

Comment: I like this simple method making sure the source and target folders are not present before creating the junction. Creating the junction creates the source folder, but not the target folder. So I had to manually create the target folder and then all is functioning as expected.

Comment: This fixed it for me but would be nice to have an explanation as to why the %AppData% fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add that the error you mentioned in your comment above `System cannot find the path specified` appears to happen when you are symbolically linking at a folder sub-level which doesn't exist at the link's original source.

Meaning you can't link

```
"c:\program files (x86)\some folder1\some folder2\"
```

to target

```
"d:\programs\some folder1\some folder2\"
```

It will not work unless at least

```
"c:\program files (x86)\some folder1"
```

exists as part of the link source. You would have to either link

```
"c:\program files (x86)\some folder1"
```

to

```
"g:\programs\some folder1"
```

or you would have to create at least an empty folder at

```
"c:\program files (x86)\some folder1"
```

and then create the link

```
"c:\program files (x86)\some folder1\some folder2"
```

to

```
"g:\programs\some folder1\some folder2"
```

Comment: This seems like a bug on Microsoft's part, but this answer is actually correct. When you link `C:\foo` to `E:\` for instance, `E:\foo` must exist to cd into `C:\foo`; however, when you *do* cd, you're placed into `E:\` -- **not** `E:\foo`. Thanks for pointing this out, I would have never figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ransomware Protection can also cause this when you have "Controlled Folder Access" enabled.

1. Press the Windows Key (or click the Start Menu)
2. Start typing "Ransomware"
3. Open "Ransomware Protection"
4. Click "Block History"
5. Click to expand the most recent item (assuming you've just got the error)
6. Click "Yes" on the UAC (User Account Control) dialog that pops up
7. Confirm the app (e.g. cmd.exe) and "Protected folder" listed
8. Click "Actions" and choose "Allow on device"
9. Re-run the command