# Tried to backup iPhone to external drive by mklink/J. Now it won't backup at all

Tags: windows-10, backup, iphone, symbolic-link

I intended to use this command:

```
mklink/J "C:\Users\DELL\Appdata\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "G:\iPhoneBackup"
```

to directly backup my iPhone to the folder *iPhoneBackup* on an external hard drive `G:`. However, when I used the command, it gave a syntax error.

So I used quotation marks around "Apple Computer" like this, which I now realize was incorrect:

```
mklink/J "C:\Users\DELL\Appdata\Roaming\"Apple Computer"\MobileSync\Backup" "G:\iPhoneBackup"
```

and noticed the result was not something I wanted. I didn't understand what this had done, it was definitely not what I had intended:

```
Junction created for C:\Users\DELL\Appdata\Roaming\Apple <<===>> Computer\MobileSync\BackupG:\iPhoneBackup
```

Now, no matter what modification I make, I get the error
`Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` I tried all the solutions in [this Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/597551/mklink-error-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists/597552#597552) but nothing works. I still get the same message.

On the other, hand when I'm trying to backup my iPhone according to the original instructions [here](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/backup-iphone-external-drive-72349.html), I get an error:

```
iTunes could not back up the iPhone because the iPhone disconnected
```

Even though my iPhone and the hard disk are both connected to my PC.

I would really appreciate any help to fix this problem.

Comment: How did the initial command fail?

Comment: It didn't create a junction between the source Backup folder in C drive and the iPhoneBackup folder in the external G drive. It did create a junction but for some other folder I can't locate.

Comment: Weird... the first version should just work. You could try to locate the junction you created maybe check https://superuser.com/questions/823959/how-to-view-all-the-symbolic-links-junction-points-hard-links-in-a-folder-using but that shouldn't affect how iphone backup behaves.

Comment: I listed all the available junctions on my computer and the one I intended is there...
So I'm wondering does is the problem because I manually removed my iPhone backups from the backup folder in explorer, and not from iTunes?