# Using external drive to backup iPhone – issues with backup now on both locations

Tags: external-hard-drive, mklink

I used the instructions to establish a link to an external drive
in [mklink error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists](https://superuser.com/q/597551/354511),
but now have both the `C:` and the external drive `D:` with a backup when I only wanted the `D:` version. I had deleted the backup in `C:` before starting the backup.

I also confirm that the only instruction that worked was:

```
mklink /J "%APPDATA%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "D:\iPhoneBackup"
```

where iPhoneBackup is the folder I established in `D:`.
I appreciate your input.

Comment: "I used your instructions to establish a link to an external drive" - Which instructions have you used specifically?  There are multiple answers to the question you have referenced.